# Do we need a Schengen visa?

Tags: visas, schengen, filipino-citizens, spouses, uk-residents

I get confused with all this.

I am Norwegian living in the UK with my wife who has a UK resident card and a Phillipine passport.

We plan to go to Spain for a holiday. Does she need a visa? we will be traveling together.

What kind of visa does she need? We plan to go to Portugal at the same time.

Comment: UK residence card neither Phillippine passport is not valid for travel to Schengen area. So she needs a schengen visa from spanish embassy in the UK. http://www.exteriores.gob.es/Consulados/LONDRES/en/Consulado/Pages/CheckPassport.aspx

Answer (score 11):

> Does she need a visa?  We will be traveling together.

Maybe.

If your wife's residence card notes that it is the residence card of the family member of an EEA national, then she can travel with you in the EU without needing a visa.  If the residence card does not have this notation (for example, if she acquired her residence through employment, or through essentially any avenue other than being your wife), then Spain can require her to have a visa, and, more importantly, the airline won't let her board without one.

Residence cards with the required notation are sometimes called *Article 10* cards, after the relevant article in the freedom of movement directive, 2004/38/EC.

> In that case, what kind of visa?

If your wife doesn't have an article 10 card, then she should apply for a Schengen short-stay visa using the normal form.  The visa should be considered using an accelerated procedure, and the grounds for refusal of the visa are limited.  In particular, it is not necessary to prove financial means.

Accordingly, the application form indicates that several questions are not to be answered by those applying as family members of EU or EEA citizens, and she should obviously ignore those questions.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a visa if you have a schengen resident card   with a Philippine passport. I have a Slovenia resident card with a Philippine passport. We go to Spain for a holiday once a year and I never encounter problems. Just one thing, before you check in you have to get a stamp in your ticket and passport at the immigration window... pop in your residence card,passport and ticket. It's right there in front of a Ryan Air check in counter. Enjoy your vacation! Jenn

Comment: This is correct, but it does not address the situation in the question, because the traveler has a UK residence card, and the UK is not part of the Schengen area.